# WordPress REST API doesn't work on custom wordpress path

Tags: javascript, wordpress, rest, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm working on my first wordpress custom theme and working on a custom Gutenberg block. So far it works on my setup. But worried about when users will be installing it on different paths.
I'm making a REST API call like this:

```
function( props ) {
    if (! props.attributes.categories ){
        wp.apiFetch( {
            url: '/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/categories'
        } ).then(categories => {
            props.setAttributes ({
                categories: categories
            })
        });
    }
```

I've installed wordpress locally with MAMP on a custom path (/wordpress) instead of the main folder. So `http://localhost/wordpress/` . My question is, the API URL                  `url: '/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/categories'` works because I've specified the exact path, adding `/wordpress/` in front of the usual path, but how can I make it dynamic so that it works for whatever path users install their wordpress site to?

Doing just `url: '/wp-json/wp/v2/categories'` will work fine for any user as long as wordpress is installed on the index folder. But what if a user decides to install my theme&plugin on a wordpress site under a custom path e.g `theme.com/wordpress-subfolder/` ?

Thanks in advance to everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Localize your script with the value of get_rest_url().

```
wp_register_script( 'my-script' , 'path/to/the-script.js' );
wp_localize_script( 'my_script' , 'wpRestApi' , array( 'url' => get_rest_url() ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script' );
```

In the js, you can access the url with wpRestApi.url

```
wpRestApi.url + 'wp/v2/categories'
```